# RSA, proof of correct work, if p is not a prime number

Tags: rsa

Is there any proof of correct work of RSA algorithm, if p is not a prime number? For example: n = p*q, p = p1*p2, where p1 and p2 are primes.

Edit:
I found that it's called Multiprime RSA, but i didnt find proof of Correctness for it.